# Can SharedPreferences be shared among different Android applications?

Tags: android, preferences

As I checked in APIs description for getSharedPreferences(String, int),Second attribute is defining accessibility mode and can take 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to control permissions.

But there is this small note in API description:

> Note: currently this class
>   (android.content.SharedPreferences)
>   does not support use across multiple
>   processes. This will be added later.

Moreover in Mark L. Murphy book "beginning Android 2" he mentioned:

> (Eventually, preferences might be
>   shareable across applications, but
>   that is not supported as of the time
>   of this writing)

Im so confused! does this mean that MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE of getSharedPrefrences is there but NOT SUPPORTED YET in latest API level???

Thanks!
Migan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My book reference is based upon that comment.

Moreover, making any file `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` or (worse) `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` is a bad idea. You lose any hope of security.

If you wish to share data between two applications, there are a myriad of solutions, such as:

- service with an API exposed by AIDL
- service with an API exposed via commands sent via `startService()` and responses sent via a `Messenger` or `createPendingResult()` `PendingIntent` or something
- content provider
- broadcast `Intents`

All of those allow you to define permissions for integration and let you control the granularity of access.

Comment: Thanks for super complete answer! I was just confused since in J2ME, RecordStores can be easily shared among different applications by setting authorization mode to AUTHMODE_ANY, although this has no security and is not recommended. Thats why I was suprized that Android's Prefrences does not support MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE yet.