# can't retrieve shared preference from other apps Android

Tags: android

i've read that shared preferences can be retrieved from outside my application, i mean if i save a preference in X app i can retrieve it from Y app, the thing is, that's not working to me, and the question is how to do it? Here's is my code, i don't know where i went wrong:

```
final String APP = "Test"; 
        final String USER_ID = "User Id";
        String myId;

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(APP, MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (prefs.getString(USER_ID, null) == null){
            if(phoneNumber != null){
                myId = phoneNumber;
                prefs.edit().putString(USER_ID, myId).commit();
            }
            if(deviceId != null){
                myId = deviceId;
                prefs.edit().putString(USER_ID, myId).commit();
            }else{
                myId = randomId.toString();
                prefs.edit().putString(USER_ID, myId).commit();
            }
        }
```

Then i try to retrieve this preference from a different app like this:

```
final String APP = "Test"; 
        final String USER_ID = "User Id";

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(APP, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String s = sp.getString(USER_ID, null);
```

but i only get a null object, what did i do wrong? I don't my the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a look on the answer posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787785/can-sharedpreferences-be-shared-among-different-android-applications

Comment: The variable `MODE_PRIVATE` doesn't seem to ring a logic bell in your head?

Comment: interesting solution, but what i need is to save an id somewhere, where even after the application that created this id is uninstalled, the id will remain saved. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

I was actually just recently looking at this, but didn't need it in the end.

[This](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/25/getting-sharedpreferences-from-other-application-in-android/) guide looked pretty good.

Comment: the example works fine, but if i uninstall the SetData project which sets the data in SharedPreferences an re-install it the data is replaced by the default data, which is not what i spec. I want the data to stay in the preferences even if the app is re-installed. But thanks for the tips

Comment: Hmm? I have no problem with SharedPreferences and reinstalling. You're not uninstalling and then reinstalling, are you? Just reinstall on top of the current installation.

Comment: Best example out there on how to share preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `MODE_PRIVATE` instead of `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`

> public abstract SharedPreferences
> getSharedPreferences (String name, int
> mode)
>
> [...] **mode** Operating mode. Use 0
> or MODE_PRIVATE for the default
> operation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE and
> MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to control
> permissions. The bit
> MODE_MULTI_PROCESS can also be used if
> multiple processes are mutating the
> same SharedPreferences file.
> MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is always on in
> apps targetting Gingerbread (Android
> 2.3) and below, and off by default in later versions.

([getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29))