# Can an app see another apps data files in Android?

Tags: android

Can an app (say app A) browse another app's data files (/data/data/)?

I'm guessing app A doesn't have permission to do so.

Comment: no, unless the phone is rooted and your app request root access. in short, NO.

Comment: It is possible under certain circumstances, in addition to placing it in the SD. See this small and complete answer. I won't reinvent the wheel answering something that does not need to be answered, so give the guy credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4787881/489607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharing data between applications you must create a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: There are many ways besides a `ContentProvider` that you can use in order to share data in files between Android applications. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4787881/489607

Answer (score 0):

If the app's data is stored on the SD card and not in device memory, I think this is possible without a Content Provider.