# How to use a ContentProvider to store data into a file?

Tags: android, file, android-contentprovider

I need some help to store a string into a file using ContentProvider.

My scenario: I have an app "A" that needs share some data (more specifically, one string) with app "B". I've found that in this case we should use ContentProvider.

The thing is: I'm new to Android, and I **really** can't understand how to use it (providers).
I searched through the Internet and I've found just few "articles" that wasn't enough to me to understand how to create my own content provider to store that data.

Can anyone guide me on this? The close I got was with this article, but wasn't nearly enough:
http://blog.tourizo.com/2009/02/how-to-display-local-file-in-android.html

Thanks,
[]'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can use Sharedprefences with MODE_WORLD_READABLE  that is not secured. So you can use Content provider.
Refer [this](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/41133), [this](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/41133/0/page/2) and [this](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/41133/0/page/3) for a simple tutorial.

Btw Would like to quote commonsware from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787785/can-sharedpreferences-be-shared-among-different-android-applications) 
If you wish to share data between two applications, there are a myriad of solutions, such as:

1. service with an API exposed by AIDL
2. service with an API exposed via commands sent via startService() and responses sent via   a Messenger or createPendingResult() PendingIntent or something
3. content provider
4. broadcast Intents

All of those allow you to define permissions for integration and let you control the granularity of access

Comment: Updated the links mate. I hate it when the links change automatically. Cheers.