# How to get a simple message from one of my other apps?

Tags: android, apk

I have two separate APK's on Google Play. I'm planning a new version of each of them that has a new in-app purchase.

I want each of my two apps to be able to query the other one to see if the item was already purchased in the other app, so the user will not have to buy the item in both apps if they have both apps installed.

I have already released both apps and they do not have a shared ID, so I don't think that's an option, because I don't think you can change the sharedID on a published app. Also, it is possible that the user installs/uninstalls these apps in various orders, or downloads them on another device, so it is not adequate to simply make a Broadcast at the time of purchase.

Is there a way to query another app for a simple boolean response?

Comment: Are they signed with the same key?

Comment: Yes, signed with same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to query another app for a simple boolean response?

I affraid not.

most close to it would be [sharing preferences across packages](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/data-sharing-between-two-android.html), but its not officially supported, and I wouldn't count on it to work across all platforms.
or [MODE_WORLD_READABLE preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787785/can-sharedpreferences-be-shared-among-different-android-applications), but as mentioned in the answer - it's not secure, and it anyway [deprecated in API 17](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).

only 3 ways supported with android API to communicate between different apps are:

- Accessing `ContentProvider`
- sending and receiving `BroadcastReceiver`
- remote `Service` binding

I think that you can achieve easily your goal with any one of the three, although you right when you say that sending broadcast from one to another is not the safest way.

if I had to implement such feature - I would create a simple `ContentProvider` from one of the two apps, and access it from both apps to store and retrieve this shared information/data.

another good approach, would be doing some server side verification to get this information. of - course it limitations are that you need to have one, and you have your users to be connected to network for that..

Comment: The documentation on ContentProviders isn't quite clear about one thing...It says you need at least one permission in your manifest for it to work. Can it be any permission? Can I just copy one of the permissions my app already uses into the <provider> element in the manifest so users won't get a notice that there's a new permission? Since I would only be using it between my own apps (with android:protectionLevel="signature"), there shouldn't be an actual need for special permissions.

Comment: I guess the risk of doing this is that any app could read from my ContentProvider, since I can't change the protectionLevel of pre-existing Android permissions. But if I'm only storing a single boolean about whether a purchase was made, it seems like it should be safe.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something .   using content provider (not ones of the system such gallery or calander) not requiring any special user permissions.   About the security - if you afraid other apps try hack your app by accessing your content provider - you should encrypt the data somehow.