# Access variable between different applications

Tags: android, variables, android-activity

How do you make a variable that can be access from two different applications? I read somewhere that global variables cannot be access from a different application. Also for more context I am able to change the code for both of the applications. The applications are to work in par with each other if the user install both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CommonsWare has this one covered on one of his books, as suggested by his answer on this question: [Can SharedPreferences be shared among different Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787785/can-sharedpreferences-be-shared-among-different-android-applications)

To quote:
If you wish to share data between two applications, there are a myriad of solutions, such as:

```
service with an API exposed by AIDL
service with an API exposed via commands sent via startService() and responses sent via a Messenger or createPendingResult() PendingIntent or something
content provider
broadcast Intents
```

All of those allow you to define permissions for integration and let you control the granularity of access.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is writing a Service in one of the Apps providing an interface to the variable. The second app could bind to that service.

If only one app is changing it, you could send broadcasts on every change and listen in the other app for a specific intent.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea for your problem is to `create a external file` or `sqlite Database file` or some other way of storing data

like you create a **xml file on sdcard**

so that it **can be shared between any application**

**Note:**

If sensitive data is to be shared then you can use some encryption too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use content provider for this.
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html